# Allow Stripe webhook to access AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, stripe-payments

I do have a **Stripe webhook** which is successfully caught and processd in Stripe's **TEST MODE**, on http local host server.

However, when switching to Stripe's **LIVE MODE DATA**, the webhook returns status code 500, while the EC2 instance is untouched, no logs being generated.

There is no issue with Signing secrets or Stripe keys, the event never reaches the **HTTPS** endpoint of the EC2 created using a **Load Balancer**.

Stripe's support cannot pronounce to this so any suggestions of why this could happen or how to handle it is very welcome.

The error displayed on Stripe is:

```
HTTP status code 500 (Internal Server Error)
Response Failed to connect to remote host
```

I have added a whitelist middleware to the express server running on EC2:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Always inside ', req.originalUrl);
  next();
});
```

before handling the stripe webhook URL

```
app.use('/afterpayment', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), afterPaymentRoutes);
```

in order to see if Stripe event reaches the server, which is not happening.

However, if i manually enter into browser the Stripe Webhook URL, **domain/afterpayment**, the result is as expected: whitelist middleware prints the message and webhook handler takes over.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  What have you tried?  What are the full error details shown in the Stripe Dashboard for the 500?  Are you 100% certain the URL is correct?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I detailed a bit more my question. That's the point, it doesn't even matter if the URL is correct or not, the middleware with 'Always inside' print should be triggered no matter what and it isn't.

Comment: Stripe uses POST requests specifically.  When you test yourself are you making a POST request or a GET request?  Loading the URL in the browser will perform a GET request, not a POST.

Comment: Sending POST precisely, with POSTMAN, works.

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking the IPs Stripe is using, or something along those lines?  Can you confirm [the IPs Stripe uses for event delivery to webhook endpoints](https://stripe.com/docs/ips#webhook-notifications) are not blocked?

Comment: I can confirm that, yes. I allow all incoming traffic towards the load balancer under which the HTTPS EC2 is exposed, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the domain was not properly exposed on the internet.

So I have **Elastic Beanstalk** environment running a **node.js** server app on which I set a **Load Balancer** and exposed the server over **HTTPS**.

While trying to catch a `webhook` sent by a 3rd party app, like Stripe, `nothing arrived on the server`, even though I could successfully simulate POST request to the domain endpoint. The domain was also **accessible** through browser (or so it seemed).

The issue was that the domain name linked to load balancer **was not resolvable publicly on the internet**. Here are 2 useful links:

- https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html
- https://dns.google.com/query?name=&rr_type=ALL&ecs=

Running tests on them unveiled problems related to DNSSEC configuration of my domain, which was not enabled on my domain.

While following this [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-configuring-dnssec-enable-signing.html) i did:

- On Hosted Zones, under **DNSSEC signing** ->  **Enable DNSSEC signing**.
- Created **KSK** and **Customer managed CMK**
- Under **DNSSEC signing**, copied the information from **View information to create DS record**
- On **Route 53**, on **Registered Domains** -> on the domain -> **DNSSEC status**, created a new key with info from previous step

After this, all tests passed and the webhook was successfully handled.

Comment: Basically we need to have DNSSEC enabled, right? Facing a similar issue but our DNS is on Cloudflare

Comment: Yes, DNSSEC had to be enabled and configured such that those 2 tests ran successfully.

Comment: I ran the tests on both the links you mentioned and they passed, even though I don't have DNSSEC setup on the site yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, and watching this thread. In my case, the issues were a few different things. I'm forcing https to my site (elb is redirecting any traffic from 80 to 443). The app on my ec2 was accepting connections over port 80. Access to the site was working. I thought maybe stripe sending the webhook data to the elb was breaking because of the redirect. This wasn't the case. However, I had a security group that was only allowing access from my IP address (for testing). Changing this to 0.0.0.0/0 from the internet (actual production access) didn't completely fix the problem but I wanted to get things set up to as close as real-world as possible. In the stripe dashboard I created a new webhook pointing to the app endpoint I exposed for testing. From the Stripe dashboard I hit the "Send a test webhook" button. This time instead of getting a timeout the error was invalid signature. So, I knew that exposing the site to the internet was part of the problem., (Yes, I could have created a security group that only allowed access from the IP addresses where the webhook data originates from, but again - I wanted to keep this as close to production as possible thanks @justin-michael for the nudge in the right direction). My app was still using the test webhook I set up for development. When I created the new webhook it also created a new signing secret. I pulled this new webhook signing secret into my app then ran the "send test webhook" again and it was successful. So, allowing the correct access from Stripe and making sure the signing secret was correct fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Could you please specify how did you expose your EC2 over HTTPS? I added a load balancer and created an ALIAS from Route 53 to the Elastic Beanstalk. Also I redirected all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS on the load balancer. On the security group I also added 0.0.0.0/0, but this still does not fix the issue. However, if I use, for testing, the generated URL of the Elastic Beanstalk, WEBHOOK IS RECEIVED! But when adding https, something breaks.

Comment: I can't speak specifically to the beanstalk configurations as I'm using just a raw EC2. However, I'd assume that the configuration is similar? That said, the app i'm running on my ec2 is fronted with NGINX. So, the traffic hits the LB and is sent to a target group that contains the EC2. This ec2 has port 80 exposed and only allowing traffic from the LB over said port. Nginx is configured to pass requests to the application.

Comment: Could you please detail how did you exposed port 80?

Comment: There are a few ways to do it. It's going to be a tad different for different apps. I would look at something like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: thank you, i added an answer with what worked for me!